# How to solve this quadratic equation raised to the power of 6?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

How to approach this equation?
$(1+2x+3x^{2})^{6}=0$

Sorry,  I am not even sure how to approach this.  I though of simplifying it first by assuming $1$, $x$ and $x^{2}$ as cube roots of 1 (complex numbers).  However, I am not sure if I am at liberty to assume that.  And even then it seems that I still have to expand it.

Comment: Since $y^6=0$ implies $y=0$ you can solve $y=1+2x+3x^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$(1+2x+3x^2)^6=0$$ if $$1+2x+3x^2=0$$ since the exponent isn't zero.

$%edits$
By the quadratic formula we get
$$x^2+\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}=0$$
so
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{3}}$$ so no real solutions.

Comment: How would solving this equation change if it was equal to 1?

Comment: so its basiclly the same way, just instead of solving this equation $(1+2x+3x^2)^6=1$ you can solve: $1+2x+3x^2=\pm1$

Comment: In the case that $1+2x+3x^2=1$ we get $$x_1=0$$ or $x_2=-\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: in the case that $$1+2x+3x^2=-1$$ we get $$x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{3}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}i$$